# HtmlHelper extension alter the value of the property passed in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a html helper to display phone numbers for text boxes in a friendly way. Usage:

```
Html.PhoneNumberFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
```

I want it to take a number like "1111111111" and output "(111)111-1111". I have tried updating the viewdata of the html helper by grabbing the property from the expression in the html helper extension method, but that doesn't seem to work. So, Anyone know how you can update the value of a property in an expression object? Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PhoneNumberFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, string>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var value = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).Model as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length == 10)
        {
            value = string.Format("({0}){1}-{2}", value.Substring(0, 3), value.Substring(3, 3), value.Substring(6));                

            var fieldName = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
            helper.ViewData[fieldName] = value;

        }

        return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);           
    }
```

Comment: change your code where you have `value.SubString(0,3)` for example and make a local variable called `areacode` then do the same for the other 2 SubStringValues, and pass them as arguments to your string.Format method

Comment: When stepping through, the "value" variable has the correct value. Yours probably is more readable, but I'm not sure how it would solve my problem..

Comment: could you not do something like this 
`int valuePhone = 1111111111;
var valuePhoneFrmt = string.Format("{0:(###)###-####}", valuePhone);`

Comment: Like I said, that still wouldn't fix the problem of the value in the textbox not being updated with the value I set in the view data dictionary here helper.ViewData[fieldName] = value;. I would also have to cast to an integer which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom DisplayFormatAttribute for this then you only have to do is to apply it on the PhoneNumber properties.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I actually am going to need to do some other stuff in that helper as well. Also, I would have to go and change all kinds of View Models and that is much more time consuming than changing views.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you if not please explain what you're needing in order to get this to work..

This should work if you are wanting to stick with working with string values as your input

```
var formattedPhone = 
    String.Format("{0:(###)###-####}", Convert.ToInt64("1111111111"));
```

Comment: Nope. There is some problem with helper.ViewData[fieldName] = formattedStr. It doesn't actually update the model like I need it to.

Comment: is it because the value that's expected to be formatted needs to be an `Int32` value..?

Comment: I believe the `string.Format expects to return a string but it's formatted value needs to be an `Int` I tried the code that I left in the comment section above as a string it would not format but I am wondering if `IFormatProvider` is expected..either way.. the commented code works but I am still confused then as to what the issue is that you are having

Comment: could you do this then to make it work 
`String.Format("{0:(###)###-####}", Convert.ToInt64("1111111111"));`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the string format. That works fine. it's the fact that I am updating the ViewData dictionary and it doesn't seem to actually be getting updated with the new value.

Comment: my apologies I thought that the format was not being formatted properly.